# Triggering a downstream pipeline after a certain stage in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab-ci

Is it possible to trigger a downstream job after a certain job in Gitlab CI?

```
stages:
  - validate
  - plan
  - apply
  - deploy
  - destroy

validate:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - terraform validate

plan:
  stage: plan
  script:
    - terraform plan -out="planfile"
  dependencies:
    - validate
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - planfile
    untracked: false
    when: on_success
    expire_in: "30 days"

apply:
  stage: apply
  script:
    - terraform apply -input=false "planfile"
  dependencies:
    - plan
  when: manual

deploy-java-web-app:
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - apply
  trigger:
    include: java-web-app/.gitlab-ci.yml

destroy:
  stage: destroy
  script:
    - terraform destroy --auto-approve
  when: manual
```

The stage `deploy-java-web-app` I would like to have triggered right after the `apply` stage, but the problem is that the `apply` stage requires manual interaction, and the downstream job is triggered right after `plan`.

Is it possible to implement in Gitlab CI?

I have tried to put on the `dependencies` keyword, but it didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried using the needs key word?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, after carefully studying the `needs` keyword, I inserted it in my pipeline, and it solved the issue (I've updated the original question to include the final pipeline).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was suggested in the comments, one of the possible ways to solve the issue is to have the `needs` [keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#needs) within the stage that is used to trigger the downstream job (I also included `allow_failure: false` and `strategy: depend` to prevent the next jobs running before success of the downstream jobs). Thus, the pipeline from the original question would look like:

```
  stages:
  - validate
  - plan
  - apply
  - deploy
  - destroy

validate:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - terraform validate

plan:
  stage: plan
  script:
    - terraform plan -out="planfile"
  dependencies:
    - validate
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - planfile
    untracked: false
    when: on_success
    expire_in: "30 days"

apply:
  stage: apply
  script:
    - terraform apply -input=false "planfile"
  dependencies:
    - plan
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  needs: ["apply"]
  trigger:
    include: java-web-app/.gitlab-ci.yml
    strategy: depend

destroy:
  stage: destroy
  script:
    - terraform destroy --auto-approve
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false
```